# How to display background image using PHP/CSS

Tags: php, wordpress, image, background, addition

I'm looking for the clean simple solution for linking background images using PHP and CSS Any help is much appreciated!

I've read around for over an hour and can't seem to find the answer. 
[Here is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia0qv.png)

I'm expecting the image to be displayed but it is not.

Comment: what is the absolute path of the image you want to isert ?

Comment: '/assets/img/intersection 1.png'

Comment: is the image of the post since you are using wordpress (the thumbnail) ?

Comment: can you access to the image using : **https:your_host:port/assets/img/intersection 1.png**

Comment: I don't have anything of that sort.

Comment: I appreciate your time. Thank you.

Comment: what is your php code ? can you explain more what do you want ?

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to get the image to be displayed on the page using inline styles via php.

Comment: what is the url of this image including the host name ?

Comment: I'm running it on my local machine and the direct url is C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\WorthIt\assets\img I hope this helps.

Comment: what is your hostname and port where wordpress is hosted ?

Comment: http://localhost:3002

Comment: I'm so sorry for the long list of comments.

Comment: I have no problem getting images linked via img src="" using get_template_directory_uri

Comment: try **echo get_template_directory_uri();** , can you see what 's the result ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you are close! A good way to do this is to store the background image in a variable so something like this

```
$image = "http://example.com/my-image.png";
```

Double check that your image actually exists (Enter that path in your browser to check. If you are loading in the image through meta data or something like that, you can echo it to the screen with `var_dump($image));`

Next when you display your image echo it in the style tag (similar to what you have)

```
style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image;?>);"
```

And because you are using a background image, you will need to make sure you specify the area it takes up. So in your CSS, you'll want something like this

```
.background-image{
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

If your div does not have any decendants, your div must have a size, otherwise it will be 0x0 and you wont see it. You don't have to use 100% for height and width, you could use px among other things.

Comment: Thanks so much. this was answered so beautifully. I'm sure this will help a lot of people Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Who downvoted this? This is absolutely the correct answer.